# Charging DIY 3s1p Battery pack as NiMH replacement

Tags: lithium-ion, diy, reuse

I have an old appliance with a completely dead NiMH pack (about 0.2V per cell) and to blow new life into it I want to replace that with a lithium-ion pack.

The old pack was 12V so I was thinking of a 3s1p pack (that will get me close enough, I have tested it with a 11.1V lipo pack) and I do not especially care about capacity of the cells. as long as that stays about the same over a couple of years.

So it seemed unnecessary to me to do a "proper" charger with a constant current and constant voltage phase, and to just use an old 12V power supply that can supply way less then the maximum charging current of my batteries.

With the cells having a maximum charge voltage of 4.2V and me having 3 of them as long as the power supply doesn't go above 12.6V I should be fine, right?

Again capacity is not a concern for me so if the identical cells are slightly unbalanced it's not a problem.

My biggest worry is whether or not it's safe for me to hook up the 12V to the BMS (yes it has overcharge protection).

Is this plan okay?

Comment: NO, absolutely not. Lithium-ion batteries are *not* the same as NiMH and *cannot* be treated like that. You need to use a proper charger, there's no way around it. In particular, it's a bad idea to leave the batteries "trickle-charging" like is commonly done with lead acid and NiMH batteries.

Comment: Okay thank you, that clears some things up. I'm will order a 3s charger that I'll put onto the "input" of the BMS.

Just out of curiosity, if I were to attach 12V directly to a 3s pack what would happen?
From what I read cells only vent with flame when charged above 4.2V or 4.3V.

Comment: The batteries would deteriorate pretty rapidly and stop holding a charge, most likely.

Comment: They could still overheat if sufficiently low on charge and no control of the charging current. Overcharge protection is a blunt instrument to try and help keep you out of danger, it's no substitute for a proper charger.